# How to create several tables from one table using Loops in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a table with observations from the date 01.08.2016 to 30.08.2016. 
How to create 12 tables in the following way:

1. the first one contains observations from the date 01.08.2016 to 20.08.2016;
2. the second one contains observations from the date 01.08.2016 to 21.08.2016;
   ...
3. the 12th one contains observations from the date 01.08.2016 to 30.08.2016.

I think that it is better to do using loops, but dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the date is in SAS date format. You can use character comparison if your date is in character format.

The data vector still contains the observation after the output statement is executed. So as long as the condition is true, the data step will write the same observation to multiple datasets. Also, I think you will need the date comparisons till 31st August if you want 12 datasets.

```
data want1 want2 want3 ... want12;
set have;
if date <= '20AUG2016'd then output want1;
if date <= '21AUG2016'd then output want2;
if date <= '22AUG2016'd then output want3;
.
.
.
if date <= '31AUG2016'd then output want12;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to use WHERE statements than to make separate tables.  But to do either without hardcoding you need to use code generation. That is normally done using macro logic.

```
%macro split(start,stop);
%local i n;
%let n=%sysfunc(intck(day,&start,&stop));
%let n=%eval(&n+1);
DATA 
%do i=1 %to &n;
  WANT&i
%end;
;
  set have ;
%do i=1 %to &n ;
  if date <= %sysfunc(intnx(day,&start,&i-1)) then output WANT&i ;
%end;
run;
%mend split;

%split('20AUG2016'd,'31AUG2016'd);
```